# WSO2 older Version software where to download

Tags: wso2

Where can we download the previous version of these WSO2 products.

- wso2am-1.10.0.zip
- wso2brs-2.2.0.zip
- wso2dss-3.5.0.zip
- wso2esb-4.9.0.zip
- developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64-3.8.0.zip

I could see just this wso2esb-4.9.0.zip for download in the previous version list but no the other software. Any help is appreciated.

-bhu

Answer (score 1):

Here are the links.

[WSO2 API Manager previous versions](http://wso2.com/more-downloads/api-manager/)

[WSO2 DSS previous versions](http://wso2.com/more-downloads/data-services-server/)

[WSO2 developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64-3.8.0.zip download](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/)

Since the new Product WSO2 Enterprise Integrater has the Capability of old product of WSO2 BRS WSO2 site is no longer advertising to download WSO2 BRS 2.2.0 or other versions.

Comment: Thanks for link. It would be great to see this link on the official site.